psutil.disk_usage throws an exception - argument 1 (impossible<bad format char>)
Trying to use the disk_usage, following the documentation throws me an error..
According to the doc:
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.disk_usage('/')
sdiskusage(total=21378641920, used=4809781248, free=15482871808, percent=22.5)

However, the same code throws me the following exception:
argument 1 (impossible<bad format char>)

I'm using Python 3.12 on Windows, please help
EDIT:
Even trying to use "C:" as a path raises the same exception..

"C:\" - SystemError: argument 1 (impossible)


Are you on Windows? Then try "C:\\".

SystemError: argument 1 (impossible) again .. :c

check out the psutil.disk_partitions() function and example code  https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/scripts/disk_usage.py

Your installed version of psutil is not compatible with Python 3.12.  Bug report here: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/2252

What psutil and python versions are you using?

python 3.12.1, psutil 3.8.0

@jasonharper, the problem is in 3.12, please post this as an answer
